# Why is everyone still constructing parent-child views using the render method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, templating, displaylist

I dare call myself a backbone hacker. I know what the framework can do, and where its limitations are. I also have some experience with a few templating frameworks.

I've seen many tutorials where people explain how to create complex and nested views, and most of them construct it kinda partially using templates, and then within the render method of the parent view, in order to combine the templated child views

To me, this makes no sense why one should deal with the layout rendering, in the declarative code. Coming from Flex, I was taught to never do that. I always left the layout descriptions and variable bindings to the markup, and then the event handling to the declarative (View instance) code which uses this markup.

None of the templating frameworks I tested, however, allows the creation of complex markup, with nested views. One cannot really invoke a template from a template and thus instantiate a View object. This seems technically possible, especially using the data attributes, where we could specify type names.

Then, all the render method of the root level View class has to do is turn this template into HTML markup, then find out what the types of the child objects should be, create a child view instance for any of them, and keep further, in case those child objects should have child objects themselves. Every view is given a model context. Basically all the boilerplate steps that we deal with all the time, but automated at the Backbone.View level.

Anyone else thinking about this? Why does no one seem to be using this?

Comment: [trinity trivially does complex markup with nested views](https://github.com/Raynos/trinity). You also easily pre process trinity views to create Backbone View objects for all the nested views. The problem with your concept is you need a decent templating system that allows powerful inheritance, those are rare.

Comment: i have a feeling this belongs elsewhere, it's not a defined problem with your code that can be solved, it's more a discussion on best practices with parent-child views... i thus tend to see this more as a  discussion than a Q&A topic. something for the Community Wiki perhaps?

Comment: While I don't know your particular problem, it should be noted that Java's AWT library behaves in the way you describe as negative.  Layout managers position the controls list of elements.  Children are rendered recursively to build a control/container tree. Having built recursive rendering views in Backbone with Handlebars.js, I much prefer a more elegant code based solution rather than trying to hack my templates which always seems to require custom template operations.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that it is not necessary to use render at all and it is mainly reserved for re-rendering after changes to code has been made.  You can bind views directly based on CSS selectors (see the docs for this).

Additionally there is a model binding extension for Backbone which greatly simplifies data-binding and reduces the 'manual' labor required.  You might want to check it out.

http://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding

Finally I will say this about rendering parent-child relationships.  [Do not call the DOM in a loop](http://lucisferre.net/2011/10/06/dont-call-the-dom-in-a-loop/).  This is incredibly inefficient and at least one reason people will build up parent-child relationships only in the parents render method.  Having each child render itself using say jQuery will result in a lot of work for the browser (if you don't notice this in a modern browser try it in IE8).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that instantiating child views in the `render` method makes no sense. Although I'd be hesitant to fully automate the process because I often want to pass in additional arguments when initializing a child view, eg:

```
var childCollection = someLogicToCreateTheChildCollection();

new ChildView({
  collection : childCollection
});
```

So, what I end up doing instead is creating any child views I need in `initialize` and then in `render` I render the template and assign the child views to elements in the DOM.

This way my render function isn't the one declaring DOM order (like a lot of examples show by appending)—the template sets the DOM order and the render function just `setElement().render()`'s the child views.